# xss-lock NoSessionForPIU and XDG_SESSION_ID empty

Tags: logind, loginctl

Some time ago (unfortunately, I didn't look into it right away), my screen locker stopped working.

When I start `xss-lock` I get this error:

```
Error getting current session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.NoSessionForPID: PID 7822 does not belong to any known session
```

and `XDG_SESSION_ID` is undefined (according to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html it should be initialized).

Loginctl shows my session properly:

```
$ loginctl show-session 1
Id=1
User=1000
Name=alpipego
Timestamp=Tue 2020-02-18 07:47:21 CET
TimestampMonotonic=31087168
VTNr=1
Seat=seat0
TTY=tty1
Remote=no
Service=login
Scope=session-1.scope
Leader=912
Audit=1
Type=tty
Class=user
Active=yes
State=active
IdleHint=yes
IdleSinceHint=1582008441893113
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=30869591
LockedHint=no
```

Also

```
$ loginctl session-status
1 - alpipego (1000)
           Since: Tue 2020-02-18 07:47:21 CET; 2h 3min ago
          Leader: 912 (login)
            Seat: seat0; vc1
             TTY: tty1
         Service: login; type tty; class user
           State: active
            Unit: session-1.scope
                  ├─ 912 login -- alpipego
                  ├─4666 -bash
                  ├─5586 /bin/bash /usr/bin/tdm
                  ├─5967 /bin/sh /usr/bin/startx
                  ├─5999 xinit /home/alpipego/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1 -keeptty >
                  ├─6000 /usr/lib/Xorg -nolisten tcp :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.WVoS7zx4>
                  └─7322 /usr/lib/gnome-session-binary

Feb 18 07:47:21 precision login[912]: LOGIN ON tty1 BY alpipego
Feb 18 07:47:21 precision systemd[1]: Started Session 1 of user alpipego.
```

and

```
$ export -p | grep XDG
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
export XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
```

When I try to lock my session however, `loginctl lock-session 1` or `sudo loginctl lock-sessions` nothing happens. I suspect this has to do with `xss-lock` not finding my session and `XDG_SESSION_ID` not being set.

I'd be grateful for only leads on how to get `xss-lock` working here.